# Creating a numpy array from list of lists, with various data types

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, numpy

I'd like to create a `numpy` array with a list of lists. The data type should be `float, float, string`. **Why doesn't this work?** (Note: I already read this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32305363/1422096)).

```
import numpy

print numpy.array([[u'1.2', u'1.3', u'hello'], [u'1.4', u'1.5', u'hi']], dtype='f,f,str')
```

Output:

```
[[(4.2245014868923476e-39, 7.006492321624085e-44, '')
  (4.2245014868923476e-39, 7.146622168056567e-44, '')
  (9.275530846997402e-39, 9.918384925297198e-39, '')]
 [(4.2245014868923476e-39, 7.286752014489049e-44, '')
  (4.2245014868923476e-39, 7.42688186092153e-44, '')
  (9.642872831629367e-39, 0.0, '')]]
```

Comment: Note: my array is really big  in reality, so I'm looking for an efficient solution

Comment: Trying using object than a string. Then do not pass list of lists, pass them as list of  tuples.

Comment: @Dark how exactly?

Comment: Perhaps like `np.array([('1.2', '1.3', 'hello'), ('1.4', '1.5','hi')], dtype='f,f,object')`

Comment: @Dark I noticed that even with only 2 columns `[[u'1.2', u'1.3'], ..., ]`, then `dtype='f,f'` already doesn't work.

Comment: Thats because each nested list would be a 1D numpy array and a 1 D cant take more than one dtype.

Comment: what about the approach I told?

Comment: @Dark I don't think it'll work, because `np.array([[u'1.2',u '1.3'], [u'1.4', u'1.5']], dtype='f,f')` already doesn't work.

Comment: I told you to pass the list of list as list of tuples. 1D array cant take more than one dtype, if You want this to work then `np.array([[u'1.2',u'1.3'], [u'1.4', u'1.5']], dtype='f')`

Comment: What does the linked answer say about `tuples`?  You read it, but did you understand it?

Comment: @hpaulj The thing is that my input data doesn't use `tuples`, but list of lists, so I was looking, if possible, for a solution that would avoid to rewrite the list of lists into a list of tuples before doing it (for efficiency reason, because I receive a lot of data in realtime, and I'd like to avoid too much manipulations for CPU).

Comment: Do you know that the tuple conversion is expensive (as opposed to guessing)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stressed in my previous answer, and comments, the normal input for a compound dtype is a list of tuples.  To put it bluntly, that's how `np.array` is designed to work.

```
In [308]: numpy.array([[u'1.2', u'1.3', u'hello'], [u'1.4', u'1.5', u'hi']], dtype='f,f,str')
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

With a list of tuples, and an improved `dtype`:

```
In [311]: numpy.array([(u'1.2', u'1.3', u'hello'), (u'1.4', u'1.5', u'hi')], dtype='f8,f8,U10')
Out[311]: 
array([( 1.2,  1.3, 'hello'), ( 1.4,  1.5, 'hi')],
      dtype=[('f0', '<f8'), ('f1', '<f8'), ('f2', '<U10')])
```

---

A possible way around the normal list of tuples (I can't test it right now):

```
Make a zeros array of the right shape and dtype
Make an object array from the list of lists (or a 2d array of strings)
Assign columns of the 2d array to fields of the structured (a loop)
```

Looping on the few fields is usually faster than looping on the many records.

But, converting a list of lists into a list of tuples shouldn't be that expensive.

---

```
In [314]: alist = [[u'1.2', u'1.3', u'hello'], [u'1.4', u'1.5', u'hi']]
In [316]: dt = np.dtype('f8,f8,U10')
```

Setting with list of tuples:

```
In [317]: np.array([tuple(a) for a in alist], dtype=dt)
Out[317]: 
array([( 1.2,  1.3, 'hello'), ( 1.4,  1.5, 'hi')],
      dtype=[('f0', '<f8'), ('f1', '<f8'), ('f2', '<U10')])
```

Setting fields:

```
In [319]: res = np.zeros(len(alist), dtype=dt)
In [320]: temp = np.array(alist)    
In [321]: temp                    # default string dtype
Out[321]: 
array([['1.2', '1.3', 'hello'],
       ['1.4', '1.5', 'hi']],
      dtype='<U5')
In [322]: for i,n in enumerate(dt.names):
     ...:     res[n] = temp[:,i]
     ...:     
In [323]: res
Out[323]: 
array([( 1.2,  1.3, 'hello'), ( 1.4,  1.5, 'hi')],
      dtype=[('f0', '<f8'), ('f1', '<f8'), ('f2', '<U10')])
```

---

For this small case, the list of tuples approach is faster.  With a much longer one the fields might be faster, but it has to be tested

```
In [325]: timeit np.array([tuple(a) for a in alist], dtype=dt)
6.26 µs ± 6.28 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
In [326]: %%timeit
     ...: res = np.zeros(len(alist), dtype=dt)
     ...: temp = np.array(alist)
     ...: for i,n in enumerate(dt.names):
     ...:     res[n] = temp[:,i]
     ...: 
18.2 µs ± 1.63 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

But even with many rows, tuple conversion is faster:

```
In [334]: arr = np.random.randint(0,100,(100000,3)).astype('U10')
In [335]: alist = arr.tolist()
In [336]: timeit np.array([tuple(a) for a in alist], dtype=dt)
93.5 ms ± 322 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
In [337]: %%timeit
     ...: res = np.zeros(len(alist), dtype=dt)
     ...: temp = np.array(alist)
     ...: for i,n in enumerate(dt.names):
     ...:     res[n] = temp[:,i]
     ...: 
124 ms ± 114 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Pulling the tuple comprehension out of the timing loop saves some time:

```
In [341]: %%timeit temp = [tuple(a) for a in alist]
     ...: np.array(temp, dtype=dt)
     ...: 
65.4 ms ± 98.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Pulling the str array creation out of the timing:

```
In [342]: %%timeit temp = np.array(alist)
     ...: res = np.zeros(len(alist), dtype=dt)
     ...: for i,n in enumerate(dt.names):
     ...:     res[n] = temp[:,i]
     ...: 
71 ms ± 447 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Simply creating an string array from the list is more expensive than the tuple conversion.

Answer (score 0):

As I described in this post [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32304370/converting-list-of-lists-to-numpy-array-with-multiple-data-types/32305363#32305363) it works with dtype = 'object'

```
print(numpy.array([[u'1.2', u'1.3', u'hello'], [u'1.4', u'1.5', u'hi']], dtype='object'))
```

(works with python 3.7.1)