# Assigning data types to numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a list of Strings

```
    ls = ["1 , abc , 3.3" , "1 , def , 3.245" , "1 , ghi , 9.34"]
```

which I have to convert into a 3x3 numpy array with appropriate data types i.e convert to

```
    array([[1, 'abc', 3.3],
           [1, 'def', 3.245],
           [1, 'ghi', 9.34]])
```

I am currently using the following code to convert the list of strings into an array :

```
    new_array = np.array([i.split(' , ') for i in ls])
```

but the result I get is :

```
    array([['1', 'abc', '3.3'],
           ['1', 'def', '3.245'],
           ['1', 'ghi', '9.34']])
```

and using the following code to typecast :

```
    new_arr[:,0] = new_arr[:,0].astype(int)
    new_arr[:,1] = new_arr[:,1].astype(str)
    new_arr[:,2] = new_arr[:,0].astype(float)
```

How can I get the desired array with the specific data types ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting list of lists to numpy array with multiple data types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32304370/converting-list-of-lists-to-numpy-array-with-multiple-data-types)

Comment: @kabanus that solution gives out a list of tuples, I need a 2D array

Comment: Then this can't be done as far as I know - it doesn't make sense in some sense (funny). A Numpy array is really just a C matrix in a sense, so it really 'ought' to hold a single datatype (hence you get a list of tuples - a single complex type). I think this is an [XY problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem) - post what you actually want to do, and why you need this array. In any case a `pandas` dataframe is more suited to this type of table object.

Comment: In case you _don't_ have an XY problem, you should consider looking at the pandas module. Dataframes would give you the option to index your data in 2d, and of course a whole lot of data-based machinery around it. And almost certainly you could read your input conveniently into a dataframe, without creating that list of yours in the first place.